# How could the split() for Strings in Java be explained when two equal characters reside adjacently

Tags: java, string, split

In the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) for `String.split`,

The folowing are the examples. How can the last example be explained?

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these parameters:

```
Regex Limit Result
:     2     { "boo", "and:foo" }
:     5     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
:     -2    { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o     5     { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
o     -2    { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
o     0     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

Comment: Do you have another result in mind? Do you think it should be something else? Why?

Comment: Yes all "o"s must be omitted, the result should be { "b", ":and:f" }, without an empty string

Comment: Okay, but _why_ do you think so? Which sentence of the docs made you think so? I am quite confused as to where this confusion originates from.

Comment: What I think is the split occurs from around "o". As also according to documentation. When two "o"s appear back to back. why does an empty string gets created? if you use "boo:and:foo.split("o", 2), the result is { "b", "o:and:foo" } but if you use "boo:and:foo".split("o", 3), the result is  { "b", "", ":and:foo" }

Comment: Why should it not be generated? There **is** an empty string between the two "o"

Comment: In `boo:and:foo.split("o", 2)` you get two strings as a result: the part before the first "o" and everything after the first "o". In `"boo:and:foo".split("o", 3)` you get 3 strings as result: the part before the first "o", the part between the first and the second "o" (which happens to be an empty string) and the part after the second "o"

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs carefully:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.

Note that the empty string is a substring of any string, including `boo:and:foo`. If you do `"boo:and:foo".substring(2, 2)`, you will get the empty string. The empty string between the first two o's is followed by (i.e. "is terminated by") the substring "o" (the second o). The substring "o" matches the regex "o", so the empty string fulfils the requiremen:

> is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string

So it gets put into the resulting array.

The empty string after the second to last o also fulfils this criteria, and the empty string after the last o "is terminated by the end of the string". They should have been added to the array, and the array would have looked like:

```
{ "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
```

However, they are discarded from the array, because,

> If [limit] is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

"trailing empty strings" refers to the last two `""` elements in the array, which gets discarded.

Comment: "given expression" is "o"?

Comment: @Varuna Oh I see you were referring to the first quote from the docs. Yes, "expression" means "regular expression" here, which is the full term for "Regex".

Comment: "The empty string between the first two o's "is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression", so it gets put into the resulting array." What is the "another substring"?

Comment: @Varuna The empty string between the first two o's is followed by (in other words, "is terminated by") the substring "o", right? And "o" matches the regex "o". So it "is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression". The "another substring" refers to the second "o". I probably should have toned down that super-precise language that the docs used.

Comment: " is terminated by the end of the string." What is the "end of the string"? relative to the case "boo:and:foo". The two "o"s at "foo"?

Comment: @Varuna No, the empty string after the last `o` satisfies this criteria.

Comment: The problem I had was not understanding the docs but being not able to describe how the splitting works in the last example "boo:and:foo".("o", 0) particularly how splitting works when two equal characters are back to back that puts an empty string into the array that is returned. If substring "t" is terminated by "s" then shouldn't s.endsWith("t")  be false.  isn't "terminated by" mean ends with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221728/discussion-between-sweeper-and-varuna).